# Karma in IntelliJ: Test framework quit unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, angular, intellij-idea, karma-coverage

Searched for this error and nothing useful, so posting here.

I have a unit test for my Angular app and when I run it or debug it, it completes successfully. When I run code coverage, I get

```
13 11 2019 13:01:48.249:ERROR [karma-server]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Object.exports.arrayRemove (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\karma\lib\helper.js:109:26)
    at _reporters.forEach (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\karma\lib\reporters\multi.js:15:50)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at MultiReporter.removeAdapter (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\karma\lib\reporters\multi.js:15:21)
    at C:\Users\thehl\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\config\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellijReporter.js:83:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\thehl\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\config\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellijReporter.js:81:33
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
13 11 2019 13:01:48.626:ERROR [karma-server]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at _reporters.forEach (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\karma\lib\reporters\multi.js:11:61)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at MultiReporter.addAdapter (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\karma\lib\reporters\multi.js:11:21)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\karma\lib\middleware\runner.js:41:18)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at Executor.schedule (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\karma\lib\executor.js:30:20)
    at C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\karma\lib\middleware\runner.js:92:22
    at tryCatcher (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:729:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:673:18)
    at Promise._resolveCallback (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:466:57)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:559:17)
Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
    at TestCommand.runSingleTarget (C:\casenet\sources\provider-portal\portal-client\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\packages\angular\cli\models\architect-command.ts:242:21)
```

In addition, I get this in the Test Run window:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\thehl\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\config\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellijRunner.js --serverPort=9876 --protocol=http: --urlRoot=/ "--testName=^COMPONENT/CLIENT -> DynamicInputComponent "
C:\Users\thehl\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\config\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellijRunner.js:60
      throw e;
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
```

I tried a full reboot and upgrading everything that said karma to the current version.

Have no idea where to even start debugging this.

Comment: don't have issues running Angular unit tests with coverage.... Must be specific to your project setup. Can you share a project the problem can be reproduced with? It doesn't have to be your production code, try creating a dummy project with similar configuration that shows up the issue

Comment: Can you share: `karma.conf.js`, `angular.json` please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was caused by a recent change using karma-parallel. We broke up our unit tests to run in 4 separate threads with 4 separate web browsers.

I pulled all the references and definitions for karma-parallel from the package.json and from karma.conf.js. Unit tests work fine now within IntelliJ.

I'm simply going to have to roll this back every time I want to do this from now on.